# PHP mailserver failure

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

While I was working with html and php for sending mail via forms, I found this error.
My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="#">
            <input type='text' name='name'>
            <input type='email' name="email">
            <input type="number" name="mobile">
            <input type="text" name="message">
            <input type="submit" name='submit'>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 $mob = $_POST['mobile'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $subject="Enquiry";
 $query = $_POST['message'];
{
 $cname = $_POST['name'];

 $message="Name : $cname \n  email : $email \n  Message : $query \n";
 $email_from = 'person2<person2@gmail.com.com>';
 $subject = "registration";
 $message = "You have received a new message from the user <b> $cname. </b> \n". "Here is the message:\n $message".
 $to = "person1<person1@gmail.com>";
 $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
 $headers.= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
    ini_set("SMTP", "ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
    ini_set("smtp_port", "587");
    ini_set("sendmail_from", "person1@gmail.com");
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
     echo "<script>alert('Dear User, You Are Successfully Registered')</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "It was a problem!";
    }
    
}
?>
```

Error:

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" port 587, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

I tried many websites and answers to similar question in this only but I could not understand anything.
Can anyone please tell me the cause and solution?

Comment: You can send an email without using `ini_set()`, you should look up your php.ini and changing the settings of your smtp

Comment: Actually before I was trying to send without email only but that error said to use ```ini_set()```. By the way thanks to both of you, I will try changing my settings in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the mailserver again and as it says check you SMPT in your php file